# # symbol when discussing Java Class/Field

Tags: java, class, field

I hope this is not off topic.

I have seen people provide this symbol when referring to java class methods. What exactly does this notation mean?

> SomeClass#someMethod()

Is it a nice way to refer to a non-static method "someMethod" of class "SomeClass" without having to define the name of some instance of the class?

Comment: The "#" is somewhat analogous to HTTP url notation in JavaDoc.  It means "Look at the SomeClass, then jump to someMethod"

Comment: Also, specifically in JavaDocs, it causes a link to the right place if it is inside a `@see` or `@link` element.

Comment: The method can be static aswell, you still use `#` in the docs.